# How to use Foreign Keys with a OneToMany relationship using JDBC-PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, orm, foreign-keys

I am building a web application using:

- JSF/Primefaces/Java EE
- Tomcat
- MySQL Workbench.

My question is how do create objects with foreign keys using JDBC and prepared statements.Basically i want to store a farm object that has many field/paddock objects related to it so i need to use foreign keys. I have been reading up online about this (ORM) and people seem to use entity beans, Spring DAO or Hibernate,

However, i am have no experience in using these technologies. So i was wondering if it is possible to use foreign keys with JDBC and vanilla prime faces or do i have to use the other ORM technologies. Here is my database entry code.`

```
     public String addPaddock() throws SQLException {

    int insert = 0;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
             String sql = "INSERT INTO demeterapp.paddock(lat,lng,area,idFarm)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

             ps = (PreparedStatement) DBConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (DBConn != null) {

             for (LatLng coord : map.coordList) {



                   ps.setString(1,String.valueOf (coord.getLat()));
                   ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(coord.getLng()));
                   ps.addBatch();

             }


           ps.executeBatch();


           // System.out.println(insert);
            //System.out.println("Data Added Successfully");
        }
```

`

Comment: I did not get the question well but it appears to be out of JSF/PrimeFaces scope. You may want to retag it to be better focused by users interested in  Java/JDBC and/or ORM framework/s of your interest.

Comment: Only valid tags here seem to be jdbc and orm.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the advice , ill re tagged them